# WSUS can't see clients, MOM can't install agent

Tags: wsus, mom, microsoft-forefront

I've been tasked with testing Microsoft Forefront Client Security for a public university, and ive sort of lost myself in this process.

My ultimate goals were to create a Test OU (done) drop a few computers into the OU, deploy FCS through WSUS to them, and then violently accost them with viruses and malware.

Thus far I have:
-installed FCS server components (1 server topo) on a WS2008 VM running on ESX.
-created a test OU
-created and linked the FCS policy
-created and linked a policy to point to the WSUS on the test server (don't want to get the schools primary WSUS server involved)

Now what im trying to do is get MOM to manage these clients, and then get WSUS to deploy the client software.  however i have some problems

Problem 1: WSUS(on FCS server) cannot see any of the computers in the test OU (is there a way to override domain level WSUS GPO's?)

Problem 2: MOM will not install the agents on the client machines, saying it can't connect to the database

so where do I go from here?
thanks

Comment: Try this: Start-Run: wuauclt.exe /detectnow and then, check the windowsupdate.log in C:\Windows and check which server your client sincs for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your GPO is enforced, it will be applied. Make sure it's applied to the right group/computers.

Then, type: wuauclt.exe /detectnow and check the log file in C:\Windows (windowsupdate.log)if the client sincs correctly with the WSUS server. If not, check your GPO settings. Make sure it's applied on computer instead of user.

You can also, before, try to update your policy by running this command: gpupdate

Then, check if it's applied to the client computer: gpresult

Let me know please.

**EDIT:**

Check this site since the error message is related to this:
- http://msmvps.com/blogs/Athif/articles/43174.aspx

Also, check your proxy settings if ever you have one.

Comment: see my above answer... since it is hueg.

Comment: well, it WAS above... now it appears to be below.

Answer (score 0):

The GPO is enforced, the OU is set to block inheritance.  ive forced group policy updates several times to no avail.  Here's what I got from the logfile

> 2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 4e8 AU Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 4e8 AU Triggering Online detection (non-interactive)
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 634 AU #############
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 634 AU ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 634 AU #########
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 634 AU <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EAD0DDE0-22E2-406D-9501-9E709DD40E3F}]
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent *************
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent *********
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent   * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent   * Criteria = "IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and   DeploymentAction='Installation' and IsAssigned=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and IsAssigned=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and IsAssigned=1 and RebootRequired=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and IsAssigned=1 and RebootRequired=1"
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent   * ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:167 1056 734 Agent   * Search Scope = {Machine}
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:183 1056 734 Misc Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\Default\wuident.cab:
>   2010-02-04 17:01:57:183 1056 734 Misc  Microsoft signed: Yes
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efd.
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efd.   Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for http://wsus:8530/selfupdate/wuident.cab. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:02:182 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efd.
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efd.   Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for http://wsus:8530/selfupdate/wuident.cab. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:03:198 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efd.
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efd.   Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for http://wsus:8530/selfupdate/wuident.cab. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:04:213 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efd.
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efd.   Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for http://wsus:8530/selfupdate/wuident.cab. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Misc WARNING: DownloadFileInternal failed for http://wsus:8530/selfupdate/wuident.cab: error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Setup FATAL: IsUpdateRequired failed with error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Setup WARNING: SelfUpdate: Default Service: IsUpdateRequired failed: 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Setup WARNING: SelfUpdate: Default Service: IsUpdateRequired failed, error = 0x80072EFD
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent   * WARNING: Skipping scan, self-update check returned 0x80072EFD
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent   * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80072EFD
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent *********
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent *************
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 734 Agent WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80072efd
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EAD0DDE0-22E2-406D-9501-9E709DD40E3F}]
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU   # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80072EFD
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU   # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80072EFD
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU #########
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EAD0DDE0-22E2-406D-9501-9E709DD40E3F}]
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU #############
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU AU setting next detection timeout to 2010-02-04 23:44:03
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229 1056 504 AU Setting AU scheduled install time to 2010-02-04 23:00:00
>   2010-02-04 17:02:10:228 1056 734 Report REPORT EVENT: {A94AC3B8-B0D0-42A9-B76B-F72FE2800D4F}
>   2010-02-04 17:02:05:229-0500 1 148 101 {D67661EB-2423-451D-BF5D-13199E37DF28} 0 80072efd SelfUpdate Failure Software Synchronization Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80072efd.